# Create Cocoapods with/without automatic reference counting

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I just started learning about creating cocoapods. I followed this tutorials and everything look okay.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332

Problems is that some project file use ARC but some doesn't. If I write this code,

```
s.requires_arc = false
```

I got error like this.

> ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/Base64/NSData+Base64.m:39:2:
>   error: This library requires automatic reference counting

If I don't write, I got another error not to use arc. How can I put both arc and non-arc files together in my cocoapods? In my build phases, I have already specified -fno-objc-arc though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requires_arc` can take an [array of files](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#requires_arc) e.g. `requires_arc = ["folder/no-arc/*"]`

Comment: Thanks. I might have a lot of files like this. 
http://imgur.com/8B0WnKj . Do I need to specify folder by folder? Or is there another easy way?

Comment: It relies on termina [file globbing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob), you can define things like `"files/**/*.md` which grabs all sorts of files